# VS Code not formatting GO Code

Tags: go, formatting, visual-studio-code

I've recently installed VS Code and the Go extensions, all in all it's really comfortable but formatting the code doesn't work, neither with ALT+Shift+F nor the context menu nor on save.

What can I get my code formatted ?

`gofmt`, `goimports` and `goreturns` work fine from the commandline. And a few days ago it all worked perfectly file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install other dependencies and they should be available on your PATH.

`gocode
godoc
godef
guru
go-outline
go-symbols
gorename
gometalinter
gotests
gopkgs
delve`

Have you installed these?

Comment: Yeah sure, or atleast I let be installed by the extension

Comment: Is it happening for all files or just a specific one?

Comment: This happens for every file

Comment: and make sure $GOPATH/bin is in your path (which is where those things get installed, I believe)

Comment: setting path to bin location should fix problem.

Comment: I have everything set up just fine on tuesday, before the update to version 0.6.44 everything worked just fine.